# Property that works in CloudHub settings is not working in properties files

Tags: java, spring, mule, cloudhub

My app uses a public encryption key in the src/main/resources directory in a subdirectory called keys. In order to access this locally, I only need to set the path to `src/main/resources/keys/<mykey>.gpg`

Because the structure is different on Cloudhub, setting the above path won't work and I instead have to set it to `${app.home}/keys/<mykey>.gpg`.
This works when I set the property directly in Cloudhub, but when I set it in my properties file, I get the error message...

```
Could not resolve placeholder 'app.home' in string value 
"${app.home}/classes/keys/<mykey>.gpg"
```

I also can't resolve the property when I run locally. My guess is that the the properties in application-${ENV}.properties are resolved first, then the ${app.home} property is set and the Cloudhub properties are resolved last.

My question is, what can I do to ensure that ${app.home} is properly resolved from the properties file, or is there another way that I can achieve the same thing without using it? Ideally, we don't want to have to set the public key location every time we redeploy the app in Cloudhub.

Thanks!

EDIT:
For greater clarity, here's where I set the property in application-DEV-properties: `cibc.public.key.location=${app.home}/classes/keys/<mykey>.gpg`

Comment: are you using mule 3? or 4?

Comment: @Ryan Carter We're using Mule 3.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is an issue in Mule 3 in certain scenarios. Can you try setting `ignore-unresolvable="true"` on the property-placeholder. It should tell spring to move onto the next place to lookup.

```
<context:property-placeholder location="your.properties" ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
```

UPDATE
Also try splitting the properties into two entries:

```
cibc.public.key.location=classes/keys/<mykey>.gpg
```

Then in your Mule config:

```
identityFile="${app.home}/${cibc.public.key.location}"
```

Comment: I tried this but I got a runtime error, "Attribute 'ignore-unresolable' is not allowed to appear in element 'context:property-placeholder'."

Comment: you're missing 'v' : 'ignore-unresolable' -> 'ignore-unresolvable'

Comment: Oh...whoops. Thanks!

Comment: So I fixed the spelling issue but when I run in Cloudhub I get the same issue where it can't find the property ${app.home}. Could it be that its' because I'm using a property within a property?

Comment: I got it to work! I basically took your suggestion of breaking up the properties into two. Since the ${app.home} property was no longer being accessed from the properties file, there was no longer any need for "ignore-unresolvable".

Since running locally doesn't use ${app.home} for the root path, I had to do a bit of logic to check the environment and use ${app.home} or src/main/resources accordingly.

Thanks for the help!